# Parsing date from xml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a date saved in xml and I am trying to parse that date then get the difference from DateTime.Now but I keep getting a format error when I try to parse the DateTime out from xml, am I formatting it right?

here is my xml

```
<Item>
<Name>John</Name>
<Date>5/4/2012</Date>
```

and my code

```
public void showItems()
    {
        using (var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var stream = file.OpenFile("Item.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {

                XElement xml = XElement.Load(stream);

                listBoxItem.ItemsSource = from item in xml.Descendants("Item")
                                            select new Ages
                                            {
                                                Name = item.Element("Name").Value,
                                                DOB = item.Element("Date").Value,
                                                DIFF = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Element("Date").Value, "m d yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)


                                              };


            }
        }}
```

and my class

```
public class Ages
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public DateTime DIFF { get; set; }

}
```

I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: ParseExact looks for an exact representation, right? So where's your slashes?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Use this code to get the date parsed correctly:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(item.Element("Date").Value, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```